# exception NumberFormatException ListView OnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, double

hey:) I would like to do somethin when I click on my ListView item but I got these Exception

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NumberFormatException)) 
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
StringToReal.invalidReal(String, boolean) line: 63  
StringToReal.parseDouble(String) line: 248  
Double.parseDouble(String) line: 295    
Double.valueOf(String) line: 332    
MainActivity$5.onItemClick(AdapterView, View, int, long) line: 719  
ListView(AdapterView).performItemClick(View, int, long) line: 299   
ListView(AbsListView).performItemClick(View, int, long) line: 1282  
ListView.performItemClick(View, int, long) line: 4450   
AbsListView$PerformClick.run() line: 3174   
AbsListView$3.run() line: 3925  
Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 733   
ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 95 
Looper.loop() line: 157 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5872    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 515  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 858  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 674 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Here is my code which gives the exception:

```
 void registerListClickCallback() {
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFave);
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, 
                int position, long idInDB) {
            Cursor cursor = myDBAF.getRow(idInDB);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                long idDB = cursor.getLong(DBAdapter.COL_ROWID);
                int Kalo = cursor.getInt(DBAdapter.COL_KALO);
                int Hydrate = cursor.getInt(DBAdapter.COL_HYDRATE);
                int Fat = cursor.getInt(DBAdapter.COL_FAT);
                int Protein = cursor.getInt(DBAdapter.COL_PROTEIN);
                 //int to double

                KalorienenVerzehrt=KalorienenVerzehrt+(double)Kalo;
                KalorienenUebrig=KalorienenUebrig-(double)Kalo;
                HydrateG=HydrateG+(double)Hydrate;
                FetteG=FetteG+(double)Fat;
                EiweisseG=EiweisseG+(double)Protein;
```

Thank you for Helping:)
 And sorry for my bad Englsih;)

Comment: Try to use KalorienenVerzehrt=KalorienenVerzehrt+Double.valueOf(Kalo) instead.

Comment: are you still getting the same Exception?

Comment: yes..hmm..I also tried to put the int values to double values and then I added these values but I doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of crash

Surround your parsing methods in a try-catch, catching NumberFormatException. If the exception occurs, notify the user they entered an invalid value and do not proceed with the calculation

```
try {
    Float value = Float.valueOf(text);

    if (value == null || value == 0f) {
        answer.setText("Zero");
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    answer.setText("Invalid input");
}
```

Comment: hmm but why is the value Zero in my Sql database the Variable has a value